# The joining operator ";" in my shell isn't working properly

Tags: c, shell

I've written a simple shell in C, and I'm trying to get the ";" operator working properly, which would be the user typing command1 ; command2 into the command line and the shell executes the first command, followed by the second command. However, it seems that, for whatever reason, it is only executing the second command. Anyone have an idea why?

Here is that particular section of my code:

```
char* next = strchr(cmd, ';');

while (next != NULL) {
    /* 'next' points to ';' */
    *next = '\0';
    input = run(cmd, input, first, 0);

    cmd = next + 1;
    next = strchr(cmd, ';');
    first = 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe something's wrong with `cmd` (e.g. it's a string literal)

Answer (score 0):

Here `strchr()` function return the value of character pointer after the semi-colon for me.

If the input is

```
ls ; ps
```

`strchr()` returns

```
; ps
```

as a result.

Use [strtok()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) instead of `strchr()`, which is used to split the string as use required.

Something like following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *str = malloc(20);
    char *tok = NULL;


    strcpy(str, "command1;command2");
    tok = strtok(str, ";");
    while (tok) 
    {
        printf("Token: %s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }

    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

See [*here*](http://rextester.com/KNNBNL63578)

Answer (score 0):

your code is working for me. Just have added the condition to handle the corner case. please check the code in below.

```
char* next = strchr(cmd, ';');
while (next != NULL) {
    /* 'next' points to ';' */
    *next = '\0';
    input = run(cmd, input, first, 0);
    printf ("%s\n",cmd );

    cmd = next + 1;
    next = strchr(cmd, ';');

    if (NULL ==next ){
     input = run(cmd, input, first, 0);
      printf ("%s\n",cmd );
    }
    first = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your edits, but when I type ls ; ps into the command line, it says segmentation fault, and then executes the second command. Any idea why?

Comment: i dont have run api. so it may crash inside it. ls ; ps is having extra space. you may try like ls;ps